# Rails: too many methods in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

TL;DR: I don't know how organise my logic domain classes.

I have the model "Application", this model is in the "core" of the App and is the way I "enter" and operate over other models like:

```
@application = Application.find(params[:application_id])
@application.payment.update_attribute 'active', true
```

or

```
   unless @application.report.status
```

or

```
   @application.set_income(params[:income][:new_income])
```

so the models Payment, Income and Report are basically empty because I initialise the Application model and from there I do things "on cascade" to change the "subordinated" models. But now the Application model has more than forty methods and 600 lines.

I'm doing it right? For instance when I want to add a new Payment I like to do :

```
payment = Payment.create params
```

inside the Application model because ActiveRecord "knows" how to handle the foreign keys automatically. I could create the payment inside the Payment model using:

```
application = Application.find(application_id)
params[:application_id] = application.id
self.create params
```

but this way, I need to set the Application.id manually and that looks more verbose and not elegant.

So --if I want to reduce my Application model--, should I create modules in APP/lib directory or should I move methods to the other models?

Comment: tough question since we don't know the 40 methods. Some could be moved to other models some to helpers. You could also build methods in the other models to elegantly create new payments, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> should I create modules in APP/lib directory

Basically, yes, that's what you should do. Although I'd probably make them classes rather than modules. The pattern it sounds like you're after is called "service Objects" (or sometimes "use cases"). What this does is takes the logic from a specific operation you want to perform, and puts it in it's own self-contained class. That class then collaborates with whatever models it needs to. So, your models stay quite small, and your "Service Classes" follow the Single Responsibility Principle. Your controllers then usually call a single "service class" to do what they need to do - so your controllers stay pretty minimal too.

If you google "rails service objects" or similar, you'll find lots of great stuff, but here's some resources to get you started.

Service objects rails casts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIp6N89PH-c

https://webuild.envato.com/blog/a-case-for-use-cases/

https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ (there's one section on service objects there)

Keep in mind, once you do start using service objects, you don't necessarily have to ALWAYS go through your `Application` model to get to the related ones. A service object might take an `application_id` and then do eg. `@payment = Payment.find_by(application_id: application_id)` and so you don't have to fetch the application instance at all and can manipulate the `@payment` variable directly.

The fact that Rails makes it "easy" and "pretty" to get to related models doesn't necessarily mean you should do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would not worry about long controller and spec files in Rails.

These files tend to get very long and the usual advice of keeping classes and methods short does not necessarily apply for controllers and their specs.

For example, in our production system `user_controller.rb` is 8500 lines long and the corresponding `user_controller_spec.rb` is 7000 lines long.

This is the length of our top 10 controllers

```
1285 app/controllers/*********_controller.rb
1430 app/controllers/***********_controller.rb
1444 app/controllers/****_controller.rb
1950 app/controllers/****_controller.rb
1994 app/controllers/********_controller.rb
2530 app/controllers/***********_controller.rb
2697 app/controllers/*********_controller.rb
2998 app/controllers/*****_controller.rb
3134 app/controllers/application_controller.rb
8737 app/controllers/users_controller.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: If your app has four models that are all tied to tables in your database (ie. leveraging ActiveRecord and inheriting from ActiveModel::Base), the framework is pretty opinionated toward using model classes.

Abstractions of the service class pattern can be useful in some cases, but give yourself a break. One of the advantages of Rails is that its supposed to remove a lot of the barriers to development, among many things, by making organization decisions for you.  Leverage your model classes.

Let's see if this starts an epic developer bickering war.

Also, its ok to create interfaces in your models for related model creation:

```
class Application < ActiveModel::Base
  has_one :payment

  def create_payment(attrs)
    payment.create(attrs)
  end
end
```

And by ok, i mean that the framework will allow this.  But remember, you're already inheriting from `ActiveModel::Base` which defines many instance methods, including `create`.

I would recommend, esp. if this is a small project and you're just getting your feet wet, to use well-named rails controllers to read and write objects to the database:

```
class ApplicationPaymentsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    application = Application.find(params[:id])
    application.create_payment(payment_params)
  end

  private

  def payment_params
    params.require(:payment).permit(:x, :y) - whatever your attr names are.
  end
end
```

The sleekness you're looking for in abstracting foreign keys in creating a relational record is taken care of for you with Rails associations:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html (good starting point)

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one (more explicit docs)

That will help you slim down models if that is your goal. Just for clarification, this is one of those things that devs are extremely opinionated on, one way or another, but the truth is that there are code smells (which should be addressed) and then there are folks who arbitrary preach file length maxes.  The most important thing in all of this is readable code.

A good litmus test for refactoring working code is put it down for a few weeks, come back to it, and if its confusing then put in some time to make it better (hopefully guided by already written test coverage).  Otherwise, enjoy what you do, especially if you're working solo.